# How to calculate the upper bound of the gredient of a multi layer ReLu neural network

Tags: gradient-descent

**Layers:** We shall denote in the following the layer number by the upper script $\ell$. We have $\ell=0$ for the input layer,  $\ell=1$ for the ﬁrst hidden layer, and $\ell=L$ for the output layer. The number of neurons in the layer $\ell$ is denoted by $d^{(\ell)}$. In particular, $d^{(0)}$ is the number of inputs and $d^{(\ell)}$ is the number of outputs.

**Weights:** The system of weights is denoted by $w_{ij}^{(\ell)}$, with $1\leq l\leq L,\  0\leq i\leq d^{\left( \ell-1\right)  },1\leq j\leq d^{\left( \ell\right)  }$. The weights has an upper bound which is denoted by $w^{\left( \ell\right)  }_{ij}< \hat{w}$. The weight $w_{ij}^{(\ell)}$ is associated with the edge that joins the ith neuron in the layer $\ell-1$ to the *j*th neuron in the layer $\ell$. The weights $w^{\left( \ell\right)  }_{0j}=b^{\left( \ell\right)  }_{j}$ are regarded as biasses. They are the weights corresponding to the fake input $x^{\left( \ell\right)  }_{0}=1$.

**Inputs and outputs:** The inputs to the network are denoted by $x_j^{(0)}$, with $1\leq j\leq d^{\left( 0\right)  }$. We denote by $x_j^{(\ell)}$ the output of the *j*th neuron in the layer. Consequently, $x_j^{(L)}$ is the network output, with $1\leq j\leq d^{\left( L\right)  }$. The notation $x_0^{(L)} = 1$ is reserved for the fake input linked to the bias corresponding to the neurons in the layer $\ell+1$.

Consider the *j*th neuron in the layer $\ell$. In its ﬁrst half, the neuron collects the information from the previous layer, as a weighted average, into the signal
$$
s_j^{(\ell)}=\sum_{i=0}^{d^{(\ell-1)}} w_{i j}^{(\ell)} x_i^{(\ell-1)}=\sum_{i=1}^{d^{(\ell-1)}} w_{i j}^{(\ell)} x_i^{(\ell-1)}+b_j^{(\ell)}
$$
In its second half, the neuron applies an ReLu function to the previous signal and outputs the value
$$
x_j^{(\ell)}=\text{ReLu}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d^{(\ell-1)}} w_{i j}^{(\ell)} x_i^{(\ell-1)}+b_j^{(\ell)}\right)
$$
This can be written in the following equivalent matrix form:
$$
X^{(\ell)}=\text{ReLu}\left(W^{(\ell)^T} X^{(\ell-1)}+B^{(\ell)}\right)
$$
where we used the notations
$$
X^{(\ell)}=\left(x_1^{(\ell)}, \ldots, x_{d^{\ell}}^{(\ell)}\right)^T, \quad W^{(\ell)}=\left(w_{i j}^{(\ell)}\right)_{i, j}, \quad B^{(\ell)}=\left(b_1^{(\ell)}, \ldots, b_{d^{\ell}}^{(\ell)}\right)^T
$$
**I need to calculate the upper bound of the gradient of this ReLu neural network, which is related to $d^{\ell}$ and the number of layers, denoted by $L$.** Specifically, I need to find a constant, $G$, that satisfies:
$$
\parallel \nabla_{\Theta } f\left( x^{\left( 0\right)  },\Theta \right)  \parallel \leq G
$$
where $\Theta$ denotes all the parameters($W,B$) in this neural network.

Comment: For each weight, write the partial derivative of the loss function with respect to this weight. Combine it with your upper bound on weights and inputs, and you'll get an answer (by guaranteeing that everything is positive, the ReLu layer will just be the identity function, and hence your network will be the linear function of the inputs).

Comment: I'm still a beginner when it comes to neural networks and especially in backpropagation. Although I have a general understanding of the method you recommended, I'm still struggling a bit. Would it be possible for you to share some of the math behind it? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/159348/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4669377/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).